# Meteor + Mongodb: is there a way to fully exclude some subdocuments from db.find()'s result?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, subdocument

One can easily manage existance of some fields in `db.find()`'s result set by specifying `fields` parameter (I use Meteor and test all queries on server side, in publishing function). Say `Meteor.collection.find({}, { fields: { 'a': false } })` tells Mongo to exclude field `a` from the result set.

However, if `a` is a subdocument, this doesn't work. Say, it has two fields: `x` and `y`. If I specify `{ 'a.x': false }`, one of these fields is excluded, but not the other. If I add `{ 'a': false}`, nothing happens.

Here is the question: is there any way to filter out from result set all fields that lie in some particular subdocuments of a document?

Comment: Hi Yeputons! Your question is not clear. If you are yeputons I know (Egor), you can ping me in twitter in Russian if it makes more sense: @imslavko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've added *both* subdocument's name and its fields names, like this: `{fieldB: false, 'fieldB.sub1': false}`. In this case, mongo ignores the outer exclusion and uses inner one. Removal of everything enclosed in `fieldB` solves the problem.

By the way, it's Mongo's behavior, not Meteor's binding's. You can easily reproduce it. Say, you have document with a field `fieldA`, which is a subdocument with two fields: `sub1` and `sub2`.

```
// Returns _id only
db.items.find({}, {fieldB: false});

// Returns fieldB.sub2
db.items.find({}, {fieldB: false, 'fieldB.sub1': false});
```

Answer (score 1):

Only works consistently with either inclusion or exclusion - not both at the same publish select

Comment: I know that and I use exclusions only. They just affect fields with exactly same names, and don't exclude corresponding subdocuments.